# disable default widgets in Responsive theme

Tags: themes, widgets

Theme: Resposive

I have added "Widget Context" and has set it to show a widget only on the start side. This works perfectly BUT on all other sides there shows a default widget "Home Widget 1" with a default text.How do I remove the default widget?
/Torbjorn

Comment: What is "Theme: Resposive"? Is this a typo or is it the theme name? Please also always add _all_ info + _all_ links.

Comment: Sorry: Responsive Theme

Comment: And what about the links? Please click the "edit" button on your question, add additional information, links, etc. Then make "progress" on your question with commenting, editing, etc. Make also sure to read through the [faq] how things work over here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the `sidebar.php`. In there, the default Sidebar `main-sidebar` is called.

If no Widgets are registered in this Sidebar, the fallback function shows a monthly Archive.

You have got two possibilities:

- Register a Widget for the Main Sidebar
- Remove the Fallback Function from `sidebar.php`. In this case, it would look like this:

  ```
  <div id="widgets" class="grid col-300 fit">
  <?php responsive_widgets(); // above widgets hook ?>

      <?php dynamic_sidebar('main-sidebar'); ?>

  <?php responsive_widgets_end(); // after widgets hook ?>
  </div><!-- end of #widgets -->
  ```

Please keep in mind that this theme has a lot of different Sidebars - so you may have to change all of them, or register the correct Widgets for each Sidebar.

Comment: When I remove all about "Home Widget 1 !" it disappears totally but I want it to appear only on the start page. I have in "Widget Context" checked it to only show on the start page but then the default home-widget-1 appears on alpa other pages.

Comment: Here is the code:

Comment: Is there anyway I could configure widgets for one page at the time?

Comment: You can add meta fields to your pages, defining which sidebar you are using there, and making a switch in the template. If you want a different Sidebar on the `home.php` you have to specify it there.